# Get Default Element Value from Annotation in Java

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have created my own annotation, which I utilize via reflection to make a decision in my code.  The annotation has a default value set for its sole element.  Is there a way I can access the default value via reflection?

**PageableRequestMapping.java (Annotation)**

```
package org.tothought.controllers.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PageableRequestMapping {
    String variablePath() default "/";
}
```

**Psuedo Code to Retrieve Default Value**

```
private int parsePageNumber(StringBuffer requestURL,
        PageableRequestMapping pageableRequestMapping) {

        String variablePath = pageableRequestMapping.variablePath();

    //Psuedo code doesn't work in Java, included to illustrate intentions   
        if(variablePath.equalsIgnoreCase(pageableRequestMapping.variablePath().default())){
           //handle default case    
        }else{
          //handle different case
        }
        return 0;
}
```

My research of the issue has turned up no examples.  I theorized this value could be accessed in a static manner through the class, but it cannot.  So I am left with two questions.

- Is it possible to get the default value of an element within an annotation?
- If so, how?

Also, I know I could hard code this value, however I would like to make the program slightly more robust.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the Method object, and then utilize [`Method#getDefaultValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDefaultValue%28%29).

```
Method method = pageableReqMapping.annotationType().getMethod("variablePath");
String variablePath = (String) method.getDefaultValue();
```

Here's a concrete example:

```
public class AnnotationTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz = Annotation.class;
    Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("value");
    String value = (String) method.getDefaultValue();
    System.out.println(value);
  }

  public @interface Annotation {
    String value() default "default value";
  }
}
```

Comment: The solution is returning null;  I'm checking to make sure its not me.  Is this code you ran?

Comment: I just figured it out and your paste reaffirmed it.  You need to get the class in a static manner.  Instead of `pageableRequestMapping.getClass` you need to use `PageableRequestMapping.class`.  I wonder why getting the class from the instance is different than statically accessing the class.  Thanks for the great answer, I appreciate it.

Comment: @kmb385 Glad to have helped. I've been testing that strange occurrence, and I've just found the reason and a solution.  `getClass()`, when called on an annotation acquired via `Class#getAnnotation(Class)`, is actually an instance of `$Proxy1`.  Another method, `annotationType()`, will return the correct annotation class. I'm editing my answer to use this, and I recommend it over accessing the class statically. http://pastie.org/5357208

Comment: So what dark crevice of the net did you find that information or did it show in your tests?

Comment: I printed the value of `getAnnotation(Annotation.class)`, which was `$Proxy1`, but removed that (and other debugging) from the test program for the purpose of showing the use of `annotationType()`.

Comment: @Vulcan I know this post is ancient, but I'm wondering _why_ we should use `pageableRequestMapping.getClass()` over `PageableRequestMapping.class`.

Comment: @Andy I'm not sure I understand your question; I haven't said we should use `pageableRequestMapping.getClass()`.

Comment: @Vulcan I guess I misread it. The comment you made that has the pastie.org link in it also says "I'm editing my answer to use this, and I recommend it over accessing the class statically." I guess my question should have read, "`pageableRequestMapping.annotationType().getMethod()` over `PageableRequestMapping.class.getMethod()`."

Comment: @Andy Typically, using the static `.class` is for static contexts, so because we have an actual instance of the annotation, it's more appropriate to use the non-static `annotation.annotationType()` over the static `Annotation.class`. However, I can't think of a case where the classes returned by `annotationType()` and `.class` are different or where using the former works when the latter doesn't.

Comment: In the case of using `getClass()` versus `.class` in non-annotation scenarios though, it is necessary to use one over the other, because it's possible that the object's class is implemented through an anonymous class, which would render the static `.class` approach unreasonable. I'm unable to think of any similar circumstances with annotations that would make `annotationType()` work while `.class` wouldn't.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, and sorry for resurrecting an old post. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, by applying your annotation on a class and retrieving it from the class via reflection:

```
@PageableRequestMapping
class MyUtilClass{
}


public String getDefaultValue(){
    PageableRequestMapping pageableRequestMapping = MyUtilClass.class.getAnnotation(PageableRequestMapping.class);
    return pageableRequestMapping.variablePath();
}
```

Comment: OP is asking how to retrieve the default value of the annotation, which is `/`, not `test`.

Comment: I know, this is an approach that is all I am saying, and it works so there is absolutely no need to mark it down.

Comment: I downvoted it because it didn't work correctly, before you edited it.  Although this works now, it's not too robust.  OP mentioned that he could store the value in a constant (like `MAPPING_DEFAULT`), and simply access that value. Your solution requires arguably more undesirable clutter than would a constant.

Comment: Yes, completely agreed @Vulcan, not denying it, I like your approach better, but just providing an alternative approach - I have +1'd your answer

Comment: this approach is useful is you need to retrieve defaults for more annotation methods as you can pass by a single object instead of checking for defined constants.
furthermore even if you define a constant holding the default value you cannot assign it to an annotation as a the default value which implies possible code update errors in the future if someone does not remember to update constants and annotations both.